# Добавление указанных символов к диапазону в имен в тексте

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть ли возможность в том же notepad ++ сделать перименование (наверное через регулярное выражение) по следующему принципу
Есть набор разных строк. у них одинаковое ТОЛЬКО количество символов. Нужно чтобы с начала каждой строки добавлялся указанный мною символ и так же в середине после заданного количества символов в имени.
Например

04823000804814CR5E3H8FZ0G2R

04605404001347fOHnxwdSeWi8x

04602824016210FJ1XOJSVPDQBL

к каждой строчке, к этим символам применяются условия - в начале добавляет 33 а после (допустим) 10го символа, вставлял 81

В результате, после переименования получится

330482300080814814CR5E3H8FZ0G2R

330460540400811347fOHnxwdSeWi8x

330460282401816210FJ1XOJSVPDQBL

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделайте замену по регулярному выражению `^(.{10})` на `33${1}81`

Comment: Я наверное нарушу правила. Но действительно большущее вам спасибо! Сэкономили кучу времени! ! Я уже думал это невозможно.

Comment: @Сергей спасибо тут выражают, если помогло, с помощью галки у ответа )

Comment: Ой)  "Слона то,  я и не заметил" .  Я сделал сразу, в первую очередь стрелочку вверх - мол "повысить репутацию", но сайт мне ответил "пользователь с рейтинком" (или рангом) ниже 15 не могут повышать рейтинг , но тем не менее тоже не останется незамеченным" .  И т.к.   я не хотел выглядеть абсолютно отморозившимся и неблагодарным человеком я решил написать) Теперь буду знать.  Ещё раз спасибо!